# How to resolve multiple simultaneous when i use Linux task-crontab

Tags: php, cron

Here has a question: I need execute a task to put many data to another mysql database per minute; if the first task hasn't finish, the second has start; so,there has a multiple  concurrent problem; how to resolve the problem??

I have some ideas, first, Let the task has a execute-time which less than the start time of next task;second, let the task support multi-process; but,i don't the how to write the code?

```
 public function execute(Input $input, Output $output)
 {
    $tele_data = Telesales::field('*')->where([['create_time','<',time()-48*3600],['customer_label','in',[2,6,7]],['virtual_sale','=','0']])->whereRaw('phone is not null')->select()->toArray();

    foreach($tele_data as $key=>$value) {
        static::pushTeleToIdc($value);
    }
}


private static function pushTeleToIdc($data = []) {

    $res = Telesales::where('id',$value['id'])->update(['virtual_sale'=>'1']);
    if(!$res) {
        return;
    }
    $url = config('idc.tele_url');
    $key = config('idc.tele_key');
    $channel = config('idc.tele_channel');
    $time = time();
    $sign = md5($key.$channel.$time);
    $urls = $url."?channel=".$channel."&sign=".$sign."&time=".$time;
    $require_params = config('idc.require_params');
    foreach($require_params as $key=>$value) {
        if(array_key_exists($key,$data) && !empty($data[$key])) {
            $d[$key] = $data[$key];
        }else{
            $d[$key] = empty($value)?'':$value[array_rand($value,1)];
        }
    }

    $d['register_time'] = $d['create_time'];

    $res =  post_url($urls,$d);
    $result = json_decode($res,true);
    if (isset($result['code']) && $result['code'] != 0){
        Log::init(['single'=>'tpushidc'])->error($res);
    }
}
```

Could you help me resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to setup a flag to tell that the process is already in progress and check if that's the case at the start of the function. I don't know how you want to setup the visibility of your code, so I leave it to you to extract $myFile to the file/class scope (same goes for the file path, you probably want to use some /var or /log folder for such stuff).

So the gist is: we create a file, if it doesn't exist or there is a 0 in it - it means we can start working. On other hand, if the contents of the file is 1, the process will die and it will be so every time you run it, until the first one finishes and rewrites the contents of the file to 0 (which means the process is not in progress anymore).

```
public function execute(Input $input, Output $output)
{
    if ($this->isProcessInProgress()) {
        die('Process is in progress');
    }

    $this->startProcess();

    $tele_data = [...];

    foreach($tele_data as $key=>$value) {
        static::pushTeleToIdc($value);
    }

    $this->finishProcess();
}

private function isProcessInProgress() {
    $myFile = 'tele_to_idc_process.txt';
    $handle = fopen($myFile, 'r');

    if (!$handle)
        return false;

    $status = fread($handle, 1);
    fclose($handle);

    return (bool) $status;
}

private function startProcess() {
    $myFile = 'tele_to_idc_process.txt';
    $handle = fopen($myFile, 'w');

    if (!$handle)
        return;

    $status = fwrite($handle, '1');

    fclose($handle);
}

private function finishProcess() {
    $myFile = 'tele_to_idc_process.txt';
    $handle = fopen($myFile, 'w');

    if (!$handle)
        return;

    $status = fwrite($handle, '0');

    fclose($handle);
}
```

You might get a warning if the file doesn't exist, you can suppress it with @fopen instead of fopen

Comment: This is a good method, thanks; but if program read file frequently,the file wile be  blocking, how to resolve the problem? and if i substituted cache for file,would it be better?

Comment: If you have caching system use that instead. I'm not sure what problem you are referring to, but this method is used in many mid sized projects throughout the world

Comment: Thank you so much;this is my first question,and your answer are my first answer;